# Auto Refresh Listview When Data in XML changed from server

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

This is my code that parsing XML from server and display in List view. I want auto refresh to display list view when data is changed from server.

```java
package com.wafik;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class vctcs extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private ListView listView;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        bindDataToListing();
}

    public void bindDataToListing() {
        try {
            SAXParserFactory saxparser = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser parser = saxparser.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xmlReader = parser.getXMLReader();
            ParsingClass pc = new ParsingClass();
            xmlReader.setContentHandler(pc);

                URL url=new URL("my url"); 
                InputStream is=url.openStream(); // Use this InputStream to parse 

            xmlReader.parse(new InputSource(is));
            BindingData bindingData = new BindingData(this, pc.name,
                    pc.address, pc.qua,pc.qua2);
            listView.setAdapter(bindingData);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }


}
```

Parsing XML

```java
package com.wafik;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class ParsingClass extends DefaultHandler {

    ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> address = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> qua = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> qua2 = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, attributes);
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("time")) {
            tempStore = "";
        } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("street_name")) {
            tempStore = "";
        } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("intersection_no")) {
            tempStore = "";
        } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("traffic_state")) {
                tempStore = "";
        }else{
            tempStore = "";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        super.endElement(uri, localName, qName);
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("time")) {
            name.add(tempStore);
        } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("street_name")) {
            address.add(tempStore);
        } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("intersection_no")) {
            qua.add(tempStore);
        }else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("traffic_state")) {
            qua2.add(tempStore);
        }
        tempStore = "";
    }

    private String tempStore = "";

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        super.characters(ch, start, length);
        tempStore += new String(ch, start, length);
    }
}
```

Binding Data

```java
package com.wafik;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BindingData extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<String> time;
    ArrayList<String> street_name;
    ArrayList<String> intersection_no;
    ArrayList<String> traffic_state;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public BindingData() {

    }

    public BindingData(Activity act, ArrayList<String> name,
            ArrayList<String> add, ArrayList<String> qua,ArrayList<String> qua2) {
        this.time = name;
        this.street_name = add;
        this.intersection_no = qua;
        this.traffic_state = qua2;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) act
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return time.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new Holder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow, null);
            holder.txttime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.txtstreet_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.address);
            holder.txtintersection_no = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.quali);
            holder.txttraffic_state = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.quali2);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.txttime.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Time : </b>" + time.get(position)));
        holder.txtstreet_name.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Street Name : </b>"
                + street_name.get(position)));
        holder.txtintersection_no.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Intersection No : </b>"
                + intersection_no.get(position)));
        holder.txttraffic_state.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Traffic State : </b>"
                + traffic_state.get(position)));

        return convertView;
    }

    private class Holder {
        TextView txttime, txtstreet_name, txtintersection_no,txttraffic_state;
    }
}
```

Comment: `help me quickly its Top Urgent`. Why is it so urgent? Please elaborate.

Comment: First you need an object to hold all these values like time, streername, etc.
then pass a list of that object, then make an `add item` method in your adapter that updates the list with new **xml**  the call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to update your `listview`

Answer (score 0):

First you need an object to hold all these values like time, streername, etc. then pass a list of that object, then make an `add item` method in your adapter that updates the list with new **xml** the call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to update your `listview` like this:

//**Binding Data**

```
        public void addItem(YourItem item){
        this.yourItemList.add(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

//YourItem

```
        public class YourItem{
        private String time;
        private String street_name;
        private String intersection_no;
        private String traffic_state;

        public YourItem(String time, String street_name, String intersection_no, String traffic_state) {
            this.time = time;
            this.street_name = street_name;
            this.intersection_no = intersection_no;
            this.traffic_state = traffic_state;
        }

        //Getters and Setters for your object fields 
    }
```

Comment: i collect the 3 classes into one class , and there is no syntax error. now i don't know where i put these method ?!
  public void addItem(YourItem item){
        this.yourItemList.add(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
@m090009

Comment: As its  written above the code you should write it in the `BindingData` class,  the important thing here is whether you choose to make this method or not what your should do is  **first** you should update your data, **then** you should call `YOUR ADAPTER` in this case `BindingData`'s `notifyDataSetChanged()` to force the adapter to refresh the view with the new data.

Comment: i have tried updating data on server and i have also put notifyDataSetChanged() . but it still as it is no change in list view although it has been changed on server .. @M090009

Comment: can you show me where are you updating your adapters data, and where are you using `onDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Also i don't see anything in your code that updates dynamically when server data is changed. The code in `public void bindDataToListing()` insures that you fetch **xml** data once, create a `BindingData` adapter with the fetched xml data. So what you need is to fetch your **xml** everytime your server updates its data or have a refresh button, after that you should update your adapter's data and call `onDataSetChanged()'

Answer (score 0):

you have to notify the list adapter that the data has changed if you want instance change in the list view, so every time the server data is changed you should call ...

```
bindingData.notifyDataSetChanged();
```